# Parsing Priapea IV

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, syntax, poetry, carmina-priapea

I'm kind of 'intermediate' Latin, and I can't find a completely satisfactory way to parse this poem (Priapea IV, Bucheler Ed. via latinlibrary):

> Obscaenas rigido deo tabellas
>   dicans ex Elephantidos libellis
>   dat donum Lalage rogatque, temptes,
>   si pictas opus edat ad figuras.

Right now, the best I can do is:

> Lalage donum obscaenas rigido deo dat
>   dicans tabellas ex Elephantidos libellis
>   rogatque: temptes (deus) opus, si ad figuras pictas edat (Lalage)

I'm not completely satisfied, because:

- I don't know why obscaenas isn't dative like rigido deo
- Reading 'ad figuras pictas edat' just seems odd. What's 'ad' doing there? I feel like I might be reading the whole second clause incorrectly

Comment: Doesn't obscenas agree with tabellas?

Comment: @Rafael for some reason I read obscaenas as the plural noun obscena, as in Ov.Met. 9.347 'obscena Priapi'. I think you're right, though, taking it as obscenus, a, um is much simpler!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Obscaenas* modifies *tabellas*, the direct object of *dicans*/*dat*.

In this context, *ad* means 'according to' (*OLD* def. 35) or 'after (a pattern, example, fashion, etc.)' (*OLD* def. 36). *Pictas figuras* isn't the direct object of *edat*, *opus* is; *ad figuras pictas* describes the manner in which that's done.

I'd rearrange the words into something like this:

> Lalage, obscaenas tabellas ex Elephantidos libellis deo rigido dicans, dat [eas] donum, rogatque [ut] temptes, si [Lalage] edat opus ad figuras pictas.

Other points:

- *Donum* is an appositive: Lalage is dedicating the tablets and giving them 'as a gift.'
- *Si* means 'to see if, in case, on the off chance that' (*OLD* def. 11) and is to be taken closely with *temptes*. Here, it's practically equivalent to *num* or *-ne* introducing an indirect question (= 'whether') (cf. *OLD* def. 13), as in Petronius, *Satyricon* 33.5:

  > *'temptemus tamen, si adhuc sorbilia sunt.'*
  >
  > 'Let us test whether they [the eggs] are still runny enough to suck.'
- The surface meaning of *opus edat* is something like 'carry out activities'; however, those words can also be used in the context of literary/artistic production, and so could also mean 'produce a work of art' – Lalage wants to produce (living) copies of the painted scenes.

Comment: thankyou, that’s helpful. So we take opus as acc, then ‘ad picturas figuras’ is adverbial. But doesn’t temptes need some kind of object? Isn’t this OLD sense 2? Is it [Lalage]?

Comment: ohhhh... temptes [the acts portrayed]

Comment: @BenjaminNagy, No, I was taking temptes without a direct object here, just with the si clause, as in Petronius 33.5: 'temptemus tamen, si adhuc sorbilia sunt' ('Let us test whether they [the eggs] are still runny enough to suck').

Comment: In that case I’m confused again :) I expect try to take a NP direct object (try the fish), or a VP in the inf. (try to escape). Test takes a DO or a conditional and then a standalone sentence in complement (your egg example). Could you give me your model translation of the temptes clause so I can see what you mean?

Comment: @BenjaminNagy. Assuming that I'm understanding the passage correctly, temptes works exactly like temptemus in the Petronius example, with a si clause instead of a dir. obj. or inf. Instead of testing whether eggs are still runny, she wants Priapus to test whether she can reproduce the sexy scenes from the illustrations.

Comment: I see (finally) how you’re parsing it. I think I am convinced. Many thanks for your patient explanations!